# Cancelling a confirmed order to double the price

Tags: united-states

I ordered 4 Items from Walmart's online store for 28$, totaling in 115 after fees and tax.

I just got at email that said they were backlogged and more people ordered before me, so there werent enough there to fulfill my order. That got me upset enough when the listing said they were in stock for that price, but whatever. Shit happens.

I go to the website to see there are 5 left, and it's now 60$. So if I want to have my order that was already confirmed over 30 hours ago, I have to pay over double what i was originally charged.

They didn't state it as a price error, as 10+ people got theirs for the same price i was supposed to. In short, they cancelled my order so they can make people pay more, for what I already payed for.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitation_to_treat

Comment: Did they ever actually charge your card for the transaction? I think that's going to be a critical question for purposes of contract law.

Comment: Theoretically, they will not charge the credit card until the item ships, although the amount will show up as pending. Errors in this area do happen. However they *also* state that they can cancel after you have been charged (and will issue a refund). If *that* is legal, it's not clear at what point there is a contract.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

It’s in the [contract](https://www.walmart.com/help/article/walmart-com-terms-of-use/f25b207926d84d79b57e6ae2327bbf12):

> The receipt of an order confirmation does not constitute our acceptance of an order or our confirmation of an offer to sell a Product. Walmart reserves the right to cancel any orders containing pricing or availability errors, with no further obligations to you, even after your receipt of an order confirmation or shipping notice from Walmart.

That’s what you agreed to.

Comment: The OP already paid for the items. That puts Walmart past the point of being allowed to move back. Furthermore, if by "*my order that was already confirmed over 30 hours ago*" the OP means that the order was confirmed *by* Walmart, that confirmation replaces and supersedes the clause you quote.

Comment: Oh, it's in the ToS? It must be totally legit and completely enforceable....

Comment: @IñakiViggers of course the OP paid - it’s an online transaction. If the contract allows cancellation then whether someone has paid (or even received goods) the contract allows cancellation.

Comment: Walmart's right to cancellation is premised on "*pricing or availability errors*". But there seems to be no *availability error* here: The OP wrote "*I go to the website to see there are 5 left*" after Walmart emailed her that there were not enough to fulfill her order. Nor is a *pricing error* apparent: The OP's description suggests that "backlogged" Walmart honored to other customers the original price, just not to the OP. Walmart cannot elude liability for [persistent?] false advertising by means of a questionable clause, let alone when coupled with email misrepresentations about its stock.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this legal?

No. Since you already paid for the items, Walmart has the obligation to perform the contract under the conditions the company itself confirmed even if its notification to you were truthful and/or WalMart incurs a loss.

The events you describe sound in Walmart's *breach of contract* and *unfair & deceptive practices*, the latter being prohibited by the consumer protection laws in your jurisdiction.

Keep evidence of what you found at the website, and make sure that your communications with Walmart are in writing. That will make it easier for you and/or the consumer protection agency to prevail on the matter.